# imWrite() returns false despite that path exists

Tags: java, opencv, javacv, opencv3.0

i am trying to write an image to a file using this line of code:

```
Highgui.imwrite(PATH_4, img_output);
```

but that line returns false despite the path exists and img_output is not empty

why that is happening.

Comment: img_output isnt empty?

Comment: Have you checked for write permissions?

Comment: @Micka no it is not empty

Comment: @Parth how to check writing permission in opencv

Comment: I mean check the path where you're saving file can create a new file by itself, user must have permission to create file on the path.

Comment: Does `PATH_4` contain the file name, or is it just the path to the directory where you want to save the file? `imwrite` expects the file name with the appropriate extension for the file type.